# regular expression with Python required

Tags: regex

I have a string path as:

> "Z:\results\cfg3\clear1"

I need a python string method to capture whatever Number comes after  cfg  but before the **\** . Note that string before **\cfg\** and after it could change, so I cannot use string length. So, basically, with following 2 versions

> "Z:\results\cfg3\clear1"
>
> "Z:\results1\enhanced\cfg1\clear2\final"

the script should return
**cfg3** and **cfg1** as the answers.

Any ideas using regular expression?
sedy

Comment: Why not just match `cfg\d+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'.*(cfg\d+).*', "Z:\results\cfg3\clear1")
['cfg3']
```